# sc.exe StartService FAILED 1053

Tags: windows, service

I called command **1** `sc.exe create myservice binpath="C:\bp.exe" start=auto` **2** `sc.exe start myservice`

No matter what service I create, I always get such an error:
`StartService FAILED 1053 
The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.`.

Service function, code:

```
package main 

import (
    "fmt"
)
func main() {
    fmt.Println("HELLO")
    var s string 
    fmt.Scanln(&s)
}
```

If i want to start another service, example: `defragsvc Optimize Driver`this service has been succesfully started! Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is really in that

> The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

A Windows service—unlike a "regular" program—is supposed to be able to participate in certain "procotol" implemented by means of certain Win32 API calls.
Basically any program which claims to be a Windows service is supposed—upon having been loaded by the service manager—to "hook into" the service subsystem by calling some Win32 API function and then sensibly respond to callbacks from that service manager.
These callbacks are what is called "control requests" in the error message.

The way to solve your problem is to reverse the approach:
instead of bashing the problem trying random things,

1. Fetch the documentation and make yourself accustomed with how a Windows service is implemented and how it interacts
   with the service manager.
2. Study the API of the Go package you're using for turning your program into a proper Windows service and see how it maps
   to the knowledge you obtained on step (1).

If, after that, you still fail at getting your solution to work,
create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and use it
to come up with another, concrete, question.